# Query for obtain role privileges for each collection mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I am searching how to obtain something like this :

```
{  _id: "myApp.appUser",
  role: "appUser",
  db: "myApp",
  privileges: [
       { resource: { db: "myApp" , collection: "" },
         actions: [ "find", "createCollection", "dbStats", "collStats" ] },
       { resource: { db: "myApp", collection: "logs" },
         actions: [ "insert" ] },
       { resource: { db: "myApp", collection: "data" },
         actions: [ "insert", "update", "remove", "compact" ] },
       { resource: { db: "myApp", collection: "system.js" },
         actions: [ "find" ] },
  ],
  roles: []
}
```

This JSON belongs to MongoDB documentation (https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/system-roles-collection/#examples).

But I didn't find the query for obtaining this.

I know that I can do :

```
db.getSiblingDB('databaseName').getRole('rolename', { showPrivileges: true } )
```

But I don't want this because I need all the privileges (actions) in the same line.

Can anyone help me ?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

A couple of approaches you can take for querying the dataset. 
First, you can run the following **[`rolesInfo`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/rolesInfo/)** command which returns both the role inheritance and the privileges for the role `appUser` defined on the `myApp` database:

```
db.runCommand(
    {
        "rolesInfo": { 
            "role": "appUser", 
            "db": "myApp" 
        },
        "showPrivileges": true
    }
)
```

The other approach would be to query the **[`system.roles`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/system-roles-collection/)** collection in the admin database as:

```
use admin
db.getCollection('system.roles').find({ "role": "appUser" })
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. 
However, the result is very similar JSON that I obtained with the initial query. 
I suppose that I have to process the text file with the JSON with bash shell. So I understand that it does not exit any way to obtain actions for each collection in the same line?
Thanks!!

Comment: Did you mean to say `exist`? The above queries give slightly different JSON results but all have the privileges and I thought this answers your question since you said `But I don't want this because I need all the privileges (actions) in the same line.`

Comment: Apart from the same line, now it is not important. The main point is to filter the answer by collection. In sql it would be "select ....  where collection = " ".

Comment: The main point is to filter the answer by collection. I would like to obtain JSON answer only for one collection. 
I would like to do something like this query: db.getCollection('system.roles').find({ "role": "mdbuezbdc", "collection": "C_UEZBD_collection1" })
The answer of MongoDB is "Fetched" but it does not answer the JSON asked.